# Counting divs with specific classes before header tag with JavaScript/JQuery in HTML-doc

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wrote a script in JS/jQuery, which is looking for h1, h2 and h3-tags in my HTML-Doc. If the script finds a header-tag, it will automatically write the content of the tag into my HTML-Doc.
So far everything is working perfectly fine, but I have some problems with the following task.

Lets say I have a h1-tag in line 90 of my HTML code. The goal is to extend the JS-Script so that it counts all occurrences of a div with a certain class which are standing before the h1-tag.

Example:

```
HTML:

<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example2"></div> <!--Should not count this one-->
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example2"></div> <!--Should not count this one-->
<div class="example"></div>
<h1>TEST</h1>
<div class="example"></div>
<div class="example"></div>
<h2>TEST2</h2>

JS-Script:
1. Spots h1-tag in line 7 of the HTML-code and saves the value 4 in a variable because there were 4
divs with the class "example" before the spotted h1-tag

2. Spots h2-tag in line 10 of the HTML-code and saves the value 6 in the same variable because there
were 6 divs with the class "example" before the spotted h2-tag
```

So far I'm clueless on how the JS-code should look like.

I hope you understood the question and know a way to help me.

Comment: what's the use case for this? Maybe it's just for practicing, I ask because sometimes it's better to simplify the data structure rather than making a more complex algorithm. For example inserting a data-attribute in the tags you want to count, or even adding an extra css class, which you can capture using querySelector

Comment: It's a task i got from the company I'm working at. I need to rebuild a Word document with HTML and have to count the occurrences of a div with a specific class, to later display it on the page.

Comment: Have a look at `prevAll()` and `prevUntil()` or https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ in general...

Comment: @Alex I'm very new to JavaScript so maybe I'm doing something wrong, I've tried prevUntil() before but it didn't work for me. Could you maybe give me like a code snippet for my example, it would help me a lot!

Comment: @Danny7 You need to post what JS code you already have and whats not working. This platform is not to code for you :)

Comment: @Alex I don't need you to code for me, i just need help with the start. So far I've tried several things but nothing worked for me. My current JS code is, like I said in the question, just the search for the tags. How should i show you my code, if I'm clueless and don't know what to do next?

Comment: @Danny7 show the code you have so far and where exactly youre stuck as a start

Comment: see: [mammoth](https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js) *Mammoth is designed to convert .docx documents, such as those created by Microsoft Word, Google Docs and LibreOffice to HTML.*

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop over the dom elements and check the nodeName property, if you hit an h1 or h2 reset the counter.
UPDATE: after rereading the question I realized you don't want to reset the counter at each header tag.. I've removed the code that resets the count.

```
let count = 0;
$('div,h1,h2,h3', 'body').each(function(){
  const node = $(this).prop('nodeName');
  if(['H1','H2'].includes(node)){
    console.log(`${count} example div's before spotting ${node} tag`);
  } else if($(this).hasClass('example')) {
    count++;
  }
});
console.log(`${count} example div's`);
```